# Getting random integer from an event handler

Tags: c#, event-handling, return-value

I want to get a random integer and return it while whole code can access the number. So I have tried something like:

```
private int randomnumber
{
    set
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomnumber = rand.Next(0, 70);
    }
```

Then how should I call it/ get the randomnumber? For example I have tried:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(randomnumber.ToString());
}
```

Then it drops this error:

> The property or indexer 'Word_Game.Form1.randomnumber' cannot be used
>   in this context because it lacks the get accessor

Comment: The error explains the problem; to be able to use the random number you need to define a getter. You've only defined a setter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a property for this it might be better to declare a normal variable:

```
private int randomnumber;
```

Then in your constructor/load method you can initialise it:

```
public YourConstructor()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    randomnumber = rand.Next(0, 70);
}
```

You should then be able to use it in the click event handler.

If you wanted it to change every time it was accessed though then you could just use a get accessor:

```
private Random rand = new Random();
private int randomnumber
{
    get
    {            
        return rand.Next(0, 70);
    }
}
```

Comment: if I state public YourConstructor() instead of private int randomnumber I get errors because it requires a return type and if I don't write a return type some classes for example get or set aren't just there. This question was more about that.

Comment: A constructor never has a return type, it's what you use to construct your object. `randomnumber` is a private variable of the class and should be initialized in the constructor or in a method that is called to initialize the object. 

You could do `private int randomnumber = new Random().Next(0, 70);` instead, I just prefer to keep initialization logic in the constructor.

Comment: Could you drop a full example of this? I would love that for better understanding.